# Error in importing videos

Tags: macos, photos.app, error, import

iPhoto in my Mac mini pops an error, upon trying to import video from the camera:

> /Users/Pat/Pictures/iPhotoLibrary.photolibrary/Import/Masters/Roll 1/EK000003.AVI
>
> Can’t import the videos because the file is an unrecognized format.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

This could be two things.

The video could be using a codec that iPhoto doesn't recognise. Unfortunately Apple don't seem to publish a list of video codec that they support. Even [Apple's listing of image file formats](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH15283) is vague.

The video could be using a recognised format but the file could be corrupt.

I would try opening the file in something that supports a wide range of video formats, like [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/). If the file doesn't open at all, there is a good chance it is corrupt. If it does open, you can check the file format with CMD + I.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear and definitive answer for iPhoto supported video formats. iPhoto will import most .mov or other QuickTime files. It also supports some versions of AVCHD.But there is no clue Apple device can accept avi as import video type. You need save that avi video file to Apple accepted mov, mp4 or m4v video first.